# Embed tag inside video tag is not working. HTML5 Video fallback is not working

Tags: html5-video, embed, quicktime, fallback

HTML5 Video tag fallback is not working for me. Embed tag without Video tag works fine.

Below code doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
   <title>Video Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>        
<video width="549" height="309" controls autoplay>
    <source src="small.3gp" type="video/3gpp">
<div>
      No Movie
    <embed width="549" height="309" autoplay="true"  type="video/quicktime" src="small.3gp">
        </div>
    </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Below code works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
   <title>Video Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed width="549" height="309" autoplay="true"  type="video/quicktime" src="small.3gp">    
</body>
</html>
```

I need to create a video player which can run any kind of video file and fallback to quick time if its not supported by native. Mp4 format works fine as its supported in native browser (Chrome , IE and FF also as decoder is already there). 
I am testing fallback for other than Mp4. like 3gp in this case. 
I have seen code examples of Video for everybody, videojs, diveintohtml5/video, but not able to execute the the above code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What will happen if my browser supports video tag but the video file is not supported. Will it go ahead and execute the embed  tag or just fail silently and dont execute the embed tag?

Comment: After continued searching over the internet, found the reason why its not working. fallback will work only when video element is not supported. If video tag is supported then it will not fallback to embed tag even if any video format is not supported. Thanks to [Scot's blog].(http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FallbackHTML5AudioTagsForASimpleMP3PodcastAreHarderThanYoudThink.aspx)

Comment: i have this issue too...

Comment: @Vikash As you have found the answer to your question, so you should also add it as one. That way it's immediately clear for other people that this question has an answer.